# OSSEC Exclude Sub-directory Alerts

Tags: ossec

I have added this rule to receive real-time alerts but I would like to modify it or add another rule so that I can exclude the sub-folder `var/www/html/wp-content/cache`

```
<directories report_changes="yes" realtime="yes" restrict=".php|.js|.py|.sh|.html" check_all="yes">/var/www</directories>
```

can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

add an ignore directive to your ossec-server.conf file.

```
<ignore>sub-dir</ignore>
```